# CPU units for AWS CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am using CloudFormation to create a AWS::ECS::CLUSTER.  I am getting confused about the CPU Units.

I can see that I can set a CPU value in these three places:

> - AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition "Cpu" Property
> - CPU value per each ContainerDefinition inside the TaskDefinition
> - CPU Parameter value passed when executing the aws cloudformation  create-stack command, parameter cpu=value

My question is, if I am using an EC2 instance that has 4 vCPU's (4096), then, are my assumptions below correct?

> 1. if each container CPU value is set to 1024, and i have two containers, should my taskDefinition CPU be set to 2048 ?
> 2. If my task definition is set to be cpu=2048, then should my create-stack cpu value be higher than 2048 but lower than 4096 ?

**Editing to add my findings in testing**

- The Cloudformation template requires a "cpu" paramteter, this value
  can be set in the template, but then is overwritten by whatever value
  you use with the 'cpu' parameter passed on the command line with the
  aws cloudformation  create-stack command
- For EC2 launch type, you do not need to set a cpu value for the task itself, only for each container
- The CPU of each container must add up to a number < the available CPU of the EC2, so for example, I am using a t2.medium which has 2 vCPU's (2048),  I have created two containers, one has cpu set to 512, the other to 1024, so I am good for the amount of total CPU

Thank you for any help!
Kim